# Was the performance of older versions of String.Equals poor due to not checking for nulls first?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, .net-1.1

I keep coming across code like this in the code base I am working on :

```
private bool Equals(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == null && s2 == null)
        return true;

    else if (s1 != null && s2 == null)
        return false;

    else if (s1 == null && s2 != null)
        return false;

    else
        return s1.CompareTo(s2) == 0;
}
```

When I asked my manager at the time about why we do this instead of just using `string.Equals(s1, s2)`, he stated it is a faster and better-performing version of comparing strings because it does the null checks first.

Is there any truth to this? Either with the current versions of .Net, or the older versions?

The code base looks like it was created with either .Net 1.1 or 2.0, and is currently on 3.5. I keep finding a lot of these micro-optimizations which may or may not have been problems with the early versions of the .Net Framework.

(In regards to the `s1.ComareTo(s2) == 0` line of code, he claimed the same string would sometimes exist more than once in memory, and the wrong version could be used to compare strings... I eventually got him to accept my use of `string.Equals(s1, s2)` instead, however perhaps this may show you how old the code is and from what timeframe my boss is from)

Comment: The fact that it uses `CompareTo` rather than `Equals` sounds like a *terrible* decision to me - consider one string of 1 million characters, and the same string which is 1 character longer, but the same for the first million characters. The code you've posted would need to check for *all* of those characters - `string.Equals` wouldn't. Indeed, rather than using `Equals` explicitly, I'd just use the `==` operator which does the same thing. Given the poor quality of the workaround for the problem, I'd suggest you should be wary of all code from the same era+developer...

Comment: @JonSkeet When I first started, I used `==` for my string comparisons and was told to change them to `.ComareTo`. After much discussion where I tried to understand his viewpoint, he agreed to the use of `string.Equals` instead. (His argument was about rare cases where strings existed multiple times in memory, and `==` not using the right one for comparison). I always assumed it was some kind of micro-optimization based on the early versions of the .Net framework because he always seemed very knowledgeable about the inner workings of older .Net code, but perhaps he was just wrong in this case.

Comment: His argument is entirely flawed. He seems to be assuming that `==` in this case would be a simple reference comparison, when it would actually use the `==(string, string)` overload, assuming both operands have a compile-time type of string. It's very easy to demonstrate the wrongness, if you want me to... http://csharppad.com/gist/fcf23ba9006f8696102e

Comment: Given this *fundamental* misunderstanding, I would be general wary of any "knowledge" about the inner workings of .NET. It could be equally inaccurate.

Comment: That code looks especially odd because it doesn't cast the strings to `object` before doing the null check, i.e. `if ((object)s1 == null)`.  Thus it's actually calling the string equality method rather than checking for reference equality with null.  The [reference source for `string.Equals`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,372d790ddae4cbb4,references) shows how to do it correctly.

Comment: I am not sure I see the value if determining if it was faster in older versions given your boss has accepted string.Equals(s1, s2) and he is confused on how == works with string.

Comment: @Frisbee There are a whole bunch of variations of .Equals methods or overrides in the code base I am working in, and I would ideally like to slowly start phasing them out as I come across them. If I can prove this was a micro-optimization from a legacy code version, or that it is definitely not an issue with the current .Net version, then I will have a much easier time of getting the code changes approved. Everyone I work with acknowledges that my former boss was the C# guru around here, so trying to change any of his code is always very difficult.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I have always questioned many things from this developer, however it helps to have confirmation from someone who is widely known for having considerable knowledge of the inner workings of C#. And your comments have led me into a lot more research into the different ways to compare strings, and their subtle differences. :)

Comment: @Rachel Cool.  But I but I think this is a case of you can prove it is not a problem with the current version.   Old code was miro-optimized is not really a compelling case for code changes.    If it works today and is faster today then so what if it was faster or slower before.

Comment: This is drastically subjective.  But it is easy to dismiss what .NET programmers had to guess at back in the days before good decompilers and the Reference Source were available.  Ultimately it doesn't matter that much whether the null check appears in the code base or the framework of course, it doesn't get faster or slower.  Making changes like this to old code that is known to work, battle-hardened and without perf issues has however always been a very bad idea.

Comment: Generally if you see a null check before a string comparison it's because that person is using the instance `Equals` method rather than the `==` operator or the static method.  You *would* need to check for nulls if you wanted to use the instance method to avoid NRE.  Odds are someone saw such null checks, didn't understand why they were there, and incorrectly assumed that they were needed for all string comparisions.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, I do remember how hard it was to find good answers to programming questions ~10 years ago, before SO even existed. I will continue to clean up (and test) code like this as I come across it in other tasks, but I am not going to go on a large-scale crusade for refactoring out all instances of this. I believe you are probably correct that there is no noticeable performance difference for doing this with the current version of the .Net framework.

Comment: @Servy Maybe in some cases, however I don't believe that is a mistake my former boss would have made. I recall one of my interview questions was about how to implement a .Equals in the most optimized way (checking first for nulls, object.equals, length, hashcode, etc before finally doing a specific check to compare objects). He truly believed that using a custom version of .Equals for strings was more reliable, optimal, and efficient than using `==`, `instance.Equals`, or `string.Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick check of the **current** .NET source for [String](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs) shows that nulls are definitely checked for.  Code for `EqualsHelper` is also in the same class.

**EDIT** Initial answer had source code for instance version of string.  This is the static version.  Regardless of version, nulls were checked for prior to calling `EqualsHelper`.

```
// Determines whether two Strings match.
[Pure]
public static bool Equals(String a, String b) {
    if ((Object)a==(Object)b) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

Comment: That is a very useful link, however do you know if there is a version of it for .Net 3.5 or earlier? My question is specifically about older versions of the .Net Framework.

Comment: @Rachel - Not that I know of.  Easiest way to get it now would be to run the 3.5 version mscorlib.dll through a decompiler (Reflector, etc.).

Comment: You've shown the instance method, the question is asking about the static version.  You *would* need to check for nulls before calling the instance version, because it'd throw a NRE if the implicit parameter were `null`, rather than returning the correct value.

Comment: @Servy - Updating answer to show source of `public static bool Equals(String a, String b)` which also checks for null before calling `EqualsHelper`

Comment: Also the question never said that it didn't check it, it just said that checking it an additional time was faster.  I highly doubt that's right, but either way, you haven't actually answered that question.

Comment: The question is the code in the OP faster.  As for null checks, when both are null, the OP code might be faster as a check for null directly could be faster the casting each null to object prior checking ==.  But my understanding is that it **should** be casting to object.  Additionally, if s1 is non-null and s2 is null, OP code will perform 3 comparisons before returning false and .NET code will perform 2.  Worse is if s1 is null and S2 is non-null,  then OP code performs 5 compares while .NET does 3.  So in the specific case when both are null, OP code **might** be faster, but not by much.

Comment: @ClayVerValen Casting to `object` is a purely compile time operation (unless it's boxing a `struct`, which isn't happening here); there is no runtime operation that it corresponds to.